# Using Generic Type

Tags: c#, windows-10, win-universal-app, sqlite-net, windows-10-universal

I want to use an own function to work with different database tables. As I'm using SQLite, the tables are filled using custom classes.
I'm trying to fill them recursively so I've created this struct and array:

```
public class cCodesPair
{
    public string cCodeKey { get; set; }
    public Type CommonCodeClass { get; set; }

    public cCodesPair(string key, Type o)
    {
        this.cCodeKey = key;
        this.CommonCodeClass = o;
    }
}

    private cCodesPair[] codesPairs = new cCodesPair[] 
    {
        new cCodesPair("DESC_UNITS", typeof(SQLEventUnits)),
        new cCodesPair("DESC_DISCIPLINE", typeof(SQLDisciplines)),
        new cCodesPair("DESC_COUNTRY", typeof(SQLCountries)),
        new cCodesPair("DESC_VIDEOS", typeof(SQLVideos)),
        new cCodesPair("DESC_ATHLETES", typeof(SQLAthletes))
    };
```

The idea of creating this, was to loop through the array to create query the table and to fill a Dictionary for each.

The function that tries to do that is:

```
    public void Load<T>(T t, SQLiteConnection conn) where T : Type
    {
        try
        {
            var query = conn.Table<T>;

            //MORE CODE...

        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception")
        }
    }
```

The function that loops through the array and calls the `Load` function is the following one:

```
    private async Task fillDictionaries()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < codesPairs.Length; i++)
        {
            MasterDescriptions m = new MasterDescriptions();
            Type t = codesPairs[i].CommonCodeClass;
            m.Load(t, conn);
        }
    }
```

But I get that the table queried has been one called `Type`.

I would like to get Tables `SQLEventUnits`, `SQLDisciplines`, etc dinamically.
Anyone knows how to?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could accomplish this with reflection, but keep in mind it may slow your application down.

Comment: @Greg could you please provide an example? I've used `Reflection` to invoke constructors of the `cCodesPair` types themselves, but I can not figure how could I use `Reflection` in this case since I don't want to invoke any methods from the types stored in the class.

Comment: Do you want to use a data table?  Or build a model?

Comment: @Greg I want to fill `Dictionaries` with the content of the tables. For that I have a generic class from which is called the method Load.

Comment: @Greg I have a Dictionary for each `cCodesPair Type`

Answer (score 0):

Do you know Microsoft Enterprise Library?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648951.aspx

Does exactly what you want to implement.
Another reference:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/657233/Enterprise-Library-6-Sqlite-Logging-and-Exceptions

Comment: It's incompatible with UAP v10.0 :'( I forgot to say that I'm working in a Universal App...